# AdMob Banner only counts as 3 impressions on long view time

Tags: android, admob, banner

I'm having some trouble with AdMob Banners in my Android App.
The user of my app stays on one view (or activity) for around 6 minutes, while seing a banner on the bottom of the screen for all of the 6 minutes. I know, that the banner automatically refreshes, and from looking on it, it does the job correctly. However, after the 6 minutes the banner always counted as exactly 3 ad_impressions. When I was looking at the banner I saw the refresh after every 70 seconds. So on a 6 minute activity, it should have been 5 ad_impressions.

I know that I only get 3 ad_impressions per banner, because my app leads a user through 8 activities. Each takes a user around 6 minutes to complete. When a user finishes all of the 8 activities, I track a post_score in firebase. When I get a post_score, I also always get exactly 24 ad_impression (8 activities times 3).

My question is: Could it be possible, that adContainer.loadAd(adRequest) only loads 3 ad banners? Do I have to refresh the banners manually on views that live longer than the time the three banners need to show up? I feel like I read this somewhere, but I can't find it anymore. I also have no idea how to manually load more banners.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Login to your admob account.

Goto banner ad and click on advance setting

[image]

Reference link - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3245199?ctx=tltp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that is not the answer to my question. I know, that there is this setting, but if I for example set this setting to 70 seconds, I only get 3 ad_impression on a 6 minutes view. Instead of 5 ad_impressions. It seems like it is always limited to 3 impressions

Comment: What is fill rate on your ad? Is it due to less inventory in country you are displaying advertisement?  Can you please overwrite methods and put logger and update your question with it? Specially onAdFailedToLoad and onAdLoaded? Also log timing in each event so that we can verify the new settings are applied to it